# Como utilizar el tamaño de una etiqueta <a> al 100% de un <li>

Tags: html, css

Buen dia mi pregunta es un tanto sencilla y me gustaria saberlo hacer de una manera correcta o una buena practica.

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <a>enlace</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

al agregar los estilos correspondientes (sin padding)
quiero que al estar posicionado en cualquier parte del elemento lista tenga la dimension de la etiqueta a en pocas palabras que etiqueta a tenga el 100% de tamaño del li y no solo al posicionarse en el texto de etiqueta a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<a>` es un elemento [inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elementos_en_l%C3%ADnea), por lo tanto no le puedes asignar dimensiones.

Tienes que cambiarlo a un elemento `block` y así le puedes dar un `width: 100%;` y tendrás todo el ancho del `<li>`:

Variante: `display: inline-block;`

```css
li {
  /* no relevante */
  list-style: none;
  width: 100px;
}

a {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  
  /* no relevante */
  color: white;
  background: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>
  <a href=".">enlace</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Variante: `display: block;`

```css
li {
    /* no relevante */
    list-style: none;
    width: 100px;
}

a {
  /* width: 100%; default */
  display: block;

  /* no relevante */
  color: white;
  background: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href=".">enlace</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @aldanux justo lo que necesitaba.

Comment: Simplemente declara `display: block;` en tu elemento `<a>`. Declarar `display: inline-block;` y después `width: 100%;` es contradictorio. ¿Para qué quieres que el navegador haga render al elemento como si fuese en línea, manteniendo las propiedades de bloque, si después le vas a cambiar el ancho a cien por ciento, exactamente lo que hace un elemento de bloque?

Comment: @Ricky_Ruiz - Contradictorio? Dirás a lo mejor una solución diferente... Yo por ejemplo: declaro **siempre** el elemento `<a>` por defecto `display: inline-block` en mis estilos css para evitar simplemente estas cosas: [mira](http://jsbin.com/vidote/edit?html,css,output)...

Comment: @aldanux Posiblemente contradictorio no sea la palabra. El demo que proporcionas es una situación diferente, hay quienes consideran que no es buena práctica cambiar propiedades tal como lo estás haciendo ahí. A lo que me refiero es que `display: inline-block` junto con `width: 100%;` delcaradas en la misma clase es equivalente a utilizar únicamente `display: block;`.

Comment: @Ricky_Ruiz - Te doy toda la razón, por eso he actualizado también mi respuesta, para que vean que hay 2 opciones si uno lo desea... Como ya te dije yo declaro siempre `<a>` por default `inline-block` por flexibilidad.

Answer (score 0):

`CSS`  para etiqueta `<a>`.

`width: 100%`

Comment: Ya intente eso @Vitmar pero no funciona
supongo que tengo que agregar un padding al li pero no estoy seguro si sea la manera las limpia y correcta

Answer (score 0):

Quizas puedes hacer :
  `<a><li>.item1.</li></a>`
Eso deberia cumplir con lo que queres hacer.

Comment: Es posible.. pero no es válido [W3C](http://www.w3c.es/) - Elementos de `block` no pueden ir dentro de elementos `inline`

Comment: @aldalux en HTML5 los enlaces pueden englobar elementos de bloque: _"The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within"_ Aquí el enlace: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element